# Bringing word into existence just by calling and using it

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, writing-style

Sometimes, when I read essays, I see that writers make up words and by using them, they bring those words into existence.

For example:

> In her article ***"Juban America"***, Ruth Behar uses the term **"Juban"**, which is just the Jewish-Cuban identity, and though we know this term doesn't exist, she uses it. We know this word doesn't exist but after using it, it is brought into existence.

Is there a single word to name this strategy or phenomenon?

Comment: I wish someone could actually help instead of disliking my question.

Comment: See also: http://www.rqna.net/qna/pyimzr-bringing-word-into-existence-just-by-calling-and-using-it.html

Comment: This question might imply a belief that only certain authorities or institutions can bring a new word "into existence", after which it becomes useable. The truth is the opposite: Only usage, initiated by a sometimes unsung coiner, can create a new word; commentators, scholars, and dictionaries merely respond to these usages, whether approvingly or not, and they survive, or not, only as a result of continued usage, or not.

Comment: @H Stephen Straight Are you saying that _wghftme_ (which I think is close to a Jasper Carrott attempt at a crossword answer) is not actually a word? But millions heard it. Oh, zlomph! / Seriously, can you find a dictionary definition of 'word' that rules out such inane strings (as I believe all should)?

Comment: I think 'zlomph' is a perfectly cromulent word.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's called a [***neologism***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism):

> **ne·ol·o·gism**
>   noun
>
> 1. a new word, meaning, usage, or phrase.
> 2. the introduction or use of new words or new senses of existing words.
> 3. a new doctrine, especially a new interpretation of sacred writings.
> 4. *Psychiatry*. a new word, often consisting of a combination of other words, that is understood only by the speaker: occurring most often in the speech of schizophrenics.
>
> — source: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/neologism)

The practice or art of creating new words is called [*neology*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neology) or [*neologizing*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neologize)—although both terms are fairly obscure.

The precise construction of this word in particular makes it a [*portmanteau*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau).

A related term is [*nonce word*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word).

Comment: OP is technically asking for the action, not the result -- when you create a neologism, we would say that you have **coined** a new word.

Comment: @starwed FWIW the Dictionary.com reference in my answer listed "the practice of using or introducing neologisms" as one definition, but I added a note on alternate forms of *neologism* which more precisely fit as a "strategy or phenomenon". *Coining a word* is good but it's not a one-word answer (*coined* would sound very odd if used out of context with a word) and there was one answer here to that effect--not sure why it was deleted.

Comment: How about neologized?

Comment: Here's a Neologism for you: Chekov's Neologism: When a Fantasy or SF author excessively creates new words, not for story purposes but merely to show how fantastical and creative the story is. ... from Chekov's Gun.

Answer (score 5):

Or simply "to coin a new word".

Answer (score 2):

If the word isn't used ever again, it is also a [Hapax Legomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapax_legomenon):

> a word which occurs only once within a context, either in the written
>   record of an entire language, in the works of an author, or in a
>   single text. The term is sometimes incorrectly used to describe a word
>   that occurs in just one of an author's works, even though it occurs
>   more than once in that work. Hapax legomenon is a transliteration of
>   Greek ἅπαξ λεγόμενον, meaning "(something) said (only) once"

Please note though, as noted in the comments, that:

> *hapax legomenon* refers to a word's appearance in a body of
>   text and to neither its origin nor its prevalence in speech

Comment: I could be wrong, but my understanding was that a hapax legomenon is not necessarily an invented word. E.g. if an author used the word *dandelion* only once in all of his/her works, that would qualify as a hapax legomenon.

Comment: you are absolutely right, the Wikipedia article I linked is pretty clear in that respect too. Thank you, I just learned that I've always misunderstood the concept